# display image in bottom of div>li

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS:

```
.clients {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 16px;    
}

.clients li {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 0px;  
    background: #f4f4f4;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    min-height:100px;
    max-height:100px;

    -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
    -o-transition: all .2s linear;
    -ms-transition: all .2s linear;
    transition: all .2s linear;
}
```

and this HTML:

```
<ul class="clients">
    <li><img src="" /></li>
    <li><img src="" /></li>
    <li><img src="" /></li>
</ul>
```

i want to make the images display at the bottom of the `clients` or in the centre horizontally as the images may be different sizes

Comment: use bottom:0; for displaying the images at bottom. Horizontal center can be done with margin 0 auto; provided width is there.

Comment: ive just tried that and also tried it in `.clients img { bottom:0; }` but it shows the same way with the images at the top

Answer (score 1):

With this solution your images can have different sizes (height is always the same, width will be different according to the image), the images will be aligned to the center horizontally and stick to the bottom.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/owpnng4k/)

HTML:

```
<ul class="clients">
    <li><img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/4/11/1397210130748/Spring-Lamb.-Image-shot-2-011.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.spacew.com/gallery/image006169.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.clients {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 16px;    
}

.clients li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px 0px;  
    background: #f4f4f4;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    height:100px;

    -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
    -o-transition: all .2s linear;
    -ms-transition: all .2s linear;
    transition: all .2s linear;
}

.clients img {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 50px;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

to get the images on the same horizontal line use the following in the `li` css

```
display: inline-block;
```

to get the images in the center, use the following in the `ul` css

```
text-align:center;
```

```css
.clients {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 16px;  
    text-align:center; /* ADD THIS */
}


.clients li {
    display: inline-block; /* ADD THIS */
    padding: 15px 0px;  
    background: #f4f4f4;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    min-height:100px;
    max-height:100px;

    -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
    -o-transition: all .2s linear;
    -ms-transition: all .2s linear;
    transition: all .2s linear;
}
img {
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="clients">
    <li><img src="http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20100424121406/howtotrainyourdragon/images/b/b5/Toothless.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20100424121406/howtotrainyourdragon/images/b/b5/Toothless.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20100424121406/howtotrainyourdragon/images/b/b5/Toothless.png" /></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i dont want the images all the same size as otherwise some may look squashed

Comment: @charlie: you do realize in your original code that you set a max height and a min height on those images...so you're making them the same height...